# Как экранировать кавычки

Tags: cmd

Требуется запустить консольную утилиту в отдельном процессе с помощью `CreateProcess` так чтобы окно консоли не закрывалось. Для этого в качестве командной строки использую примерно такую конструкцию:

```
cmd /K "util arg1 "arg2" arg3="value""
```

При этом вложенная команда имеет большое количество аргументов которые сложным образом задаются, но главное там используются вложенные кавычки. Вопрос, как их экранировать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В качестве символа экранирования в cmd используется `^`:

```
cmd /K "util arg1 ^"arg2^" arg3=^"value^""
```

Второй возможный вариант - использовать двойные кавычки `""`:

```
cmd /K "util arg1 ""arg2"" arg3=""value"""
```